# Distorted result image implementing nearest neighbour resize in Octave

Tags: image-processing, octave, image-resizing

I implemented this algorithm in Octave, the output matrix (o) was as expected according to the input matrix (c), but the output displayed in `imshow()` is not similar to the input image.

Can you help me indicating what's wrong with this?

I'm using GNU Octave 3.6.2 running on Ubuntu 12.10.

In the below examples the images were resized 2 by 2.

**Source image:**

[image]

**Output image**

[image]

**Source matrix**

```
ans(:,:,1) =

  237  255   34
  237  255   34
  255  255  255
  255  255  255
    0  255    0
    0  255    0

ans(:,:,2) =

   28  242  177
   28  242  177
  242  242  242
  242  242  242
  162  242    0
  162  242    0

ans(:,:,3) =

   36    0   76
   36    0   76
    0    0    0
    0    0    0
  232    0    0
  232    0    0
```

**Output matrix**

```
ans(:,:,1) =

   237   237   255   255    34    34
   237   237   255   255    34    34
   237   237   255   255    34    34
   237   237   255   255    34    34
   255   255   255   255   255   255
   255   255   255   255   255   255
   255   255   255   255   255   255
   255   255   255   255   255   255
     0     0   255   255     0     0
     0     0   255   255     0     0
     0     0   255   255     0     0
     0     0   255   255     0     0

ans(:,:,2) =

    28    28   242   242   177   177
    28    28   242   242   177   177
    28    28   242   242   177   177
    28    28   242   242   177   177
   242   242   242   242   242   242
   242   242   242   242   242   242
   242   242   242   242   242   242
   242   242   242   242   242   242
   162   162   242   242     0     0
   162   162   242   242     0     0
   162   162   242   242     0     0
   162   162   242   242     0     0

ans(:,:,3) =

    36    36     0     0    76    76
    36    36     0     0    76    76
    36    36     0     0    76    76
    36    36     0     0    76    76
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
   232   232     0     0     0     0
   232   232     0     0     0     0
   232   232     0     0     0     0
   232   232     0     0     0     0
```

**Source code**

```
function out_img = nneig(in_img, x_scale, y_scale);

    in_img_height = size(in_img, 1);
    in_img_width = size(in_img, 2);
    in_img_channels = size(in_img, 3);

    out_img_height = round(in_img_height * y_scale);
    out_img_width = round(in_img_width * x_scale);
    out_img_channels = in_img_channels;

    out_img = zeros(out_img_height, out_img_width, out_img_channels);

    tf_mtx = zeros(3, 3); 
    tf_mtx(1, 1) = 1 / x_scale; 
    tf_mtx(2, 2) = 1 / y_scale; 
    tf_mtx(3, 3) = 1;

    for out_channel = 1:out_img_channels
        for out_line = 1:out_img_height
            for out_col = 1:out_img_width
                org_coord_mtx = floor(tf_mtx * [out_col - 1; out_line - 1; 1]) + [1; 1; 0];
                    org_coord_line = org_coord_mtx(2, 1);
                    org_coord_col = org_coord_mtx(1, 1);
                out_img(out_line, out_col, out_channel) = in_img(org_coord_line, org_coord_col, out_channel);
            end
        end
    end

endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the class of your image. Since you created it with `zeros`, it will of class double. It should be `uint8`. You can do it by using `zeros (x, y, z, "uint8")`, or by converting the class at the end. The better option though is to use `imresize()` which already does that thinking for you (you might need to cycle through the RGB channels though, I'm not sure).

About your code, you should avoid those loops. It will really hit your performance when you have actual images which are likely to be larger. The following code should work much better as long as the scale factors are integers:

```
function b = nearestresize (a, row_scale, col_scale)
  row_idx = (1:rows (a))(ones (1, row_scale), :);
  col_idx = (1:columns (a))(ones (col_scale, 1), :);
  b = a(row_idx, col_idx, :);
endfunction
```

Anyway, you should be using `imresize` from the image package with the "nearest" method (I'm not sure how well it works with RGB images):

```
b = imresize (im, [rows cols], "nearest")
```

See the code in `imresize` to see how it works (the code I pasted above is actually from its development version). Basicall;y, in the end it all boils down to `interp2()` using the "nearest" method.

Comment: Converted the output matrix to uint8 and it worked as expected! I knew about imresize and interp, but I wanted to do it this way for academic purposes. Thanks a lot! :D Sorry that I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @marcioggs now that you have already written it, at least take a look inside `interp2()` to see how it does it. That's the beauty of Octave, you're free to see how things are done.